# how to calculate number of days between two dates including both dates

Tags: java, datetime

How to calculate number of days between two dates including both dates?

I tried this:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(startDate), new DateTime(endDate)).getDays();
```

But this excludes one day.

Please help

Comment: Then add `1` to the result. :)

Comment: ^What kocko said.

daysBetween will always include 1 of the 2 dates given (correct me if I'm wrong), so if you want both dates to be included, just add 1 to the result.

Comment: What are `startDate` and `endDate` here? You may not need the `new DateTime(...)` part at all...

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

`int days = (Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(startDate), new DateTime(endDate)).getDays()) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Or doing this:

int days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + 1;